# How to sort in XSLT for each element when all elements are siblings

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML and I want to sort on basis on City.

```
  <catalog>
   <cd>
      <City>New York</City>
      <City>Mumbai</City>
      <City>Kolkata</City>
      <City>Paris</City>
      <City>London</City>
      <City>Sydney</City>
      <City>California</City>
      <City>Vizag</City>
      <City>Uganda</City>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

I tried below XSLT to sort but it is considering only first City element and giving only one City but I want all City in sorted manner(ascending/descending).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:sort select="City"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="City"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/City">
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
  <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, using templates would be somewhat more elegant:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd/City">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="City">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```